# SSIS Validation Error "xml source adapter does not support mixed content model on complex types"

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017

I am trying to parse an XML, But I am getting an error as "XML source adapter does not support mixed content model on complex types" while using the XML Source in Dataflow.
I don't have much experience in SSIS, I need some suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite self-explanatory -- SSIS XML Source cannot handle mixed content model.
Example of mixed model data - when node text is mixed with sub nodes.

```
<description>character data <br/> more text <br/> and <strong>more data</strong></description>
```

You have to inspect your XML document and its schema, and transform it with XSLT to an XML without mixed data. It can be done with *SSIS XML Task* before running *Data Flow XML Source*.

Comment: Thanks for your response , but I did not found any such kind of elements in the XML. The issue occurred only when generating the XSD from the SSIS only. I tried with "xsd.exe" in the visual studio developer Command Prompt. It did not generate such attributes.

Comment: @SupriyaBhattacherjee, check the XSD for statements like `<xs:complexType mixed="true">` -- it is defining mixed type node. SSIS XML Source usually reports this error on finding such statements in XSD file.

Comment: The issue is due to some spaces are considered before the node, that's the reason it is taking as mixed = true.